# Make strings in array become keys in object in new array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the below array

```
let array= ['shorts', 'tees']
```

from this I want an array that looks like this

```
let newArray= [{shorts: []},{tees: []}, ]
```

can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried something? what does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop over the array with `map()` and convert each element to the object you want.  You can use the syntax `[someString]` as a property name in an object literal to create that property.

```js
let array = ['shorts', 'tees'];
let newArray = array.map(a => ({ [a]: [] }));
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: worked like a charm mate. I tried the exact same thing earlier but in mine the a was not like [a] as you have done here. Can you help me why this worked and my method just renamed the key of the objects to a?

Comment: @Jegs: In JavaScript objects you can refer to a property by its string name using an indexer.  So `myObj.prop` is the same as `myObj['prop']`.  Using this same syntax in an object literal, `{ prop: 123 }` is the same as `{ ['prop']: 123 }`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array= ['shorts', 'tees'];

let result = array.map(elem => ({[elem]: []}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array= ['shorts', 'tees']

let list = [];
for(let item of array) {
  let obj = {};
  obj[item] = [];
  list.push(obj)
}
console.log(list)
```